# Compose nested JSON with multi columns in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a csv file and trying to compose JSON from it. There are mulitple records in a file but I am just giving one set of sample records here.This structure is driven on the claimID. There is nesting on the claimLineDetail and claimSpecDiag.I guess I have to create some sort of list to handle this then the problem is how am I going to append it in the required structure. I really need some guidance here to achieve the desired result. Is it possible to break out different sections and append it later, I am not sure just assuming, as there are multiple columns.

***Code :***

```
import csv,json

data = []
with open('JsonRequestPricingMedical.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

***csv file :***

```
claimId,subscriberId,claimType,claimSubType,providerId,totalChargeAmt,claimLineNo,pos_code,procedureCode,subdiagnosisCode,svcLineFromDt,svcLineToDt,chargedAmt,clmLineUnits,presentOnAdmit,diagnosisCode
18A000730400,101924200,M,M,002664514003,585,1,11,92014,H43393,2017-06-19,2017-06-19,160,1,U,H43393
18A000730400,101924200,M,M,002664514003,585,2,12,92015,H43395,2017-06-19,2017-06-19,160,2,U,H43394
```

***Desired JSON***

```
[
  {
   "claimsHeader":" {
    "claimId": "18A000730400",
    "subscriberId": "101924200",
    "claimType":{
                    "code": "M"
                },
     "claimSubType": {
                    "code": "M"
                },  
     "providerId" :"002664514003",
     "totalChargeAmt": "585",
     "claimLineDetail" :[
                {
                "claimLineNo": "1",
                 "placeOfService": {
                           "code": "11"
                },
                 "procedureCode": {
                        "code": "92014"
                },
                "subDiagnosisCd": {
                        "code": "H43393"
                },
                "svcLineFromDt": "2017-06-19",
                "svcLineToDt": "2017-06-19",
                "chargedAmt": "160",
                "clmLineUnits": "1",
                },
                {
                "claimLineNo": "2",
                 "placeOfService": {
                           "code": "12"
                },
                 "procedureCode": {
                        "code": "92015"
                },
                "subDiagnosisCd": {
                        "code": "H433945
                },
                "svcLineFromDt": "2017-06-19",
                "svcLineToDt": "2017-06-19",
                "chargedAmt": "160",
                "clmLineUnits": "2",
                }
     ],
     {
        "claimSpecDiag": [

            "presentOnAdmit": "",
            "diagnosisCode": "H43393",

         },
         {
            "presentOnAdmit": "",
            "diagnosisCode": "H43394",
         }

    ]   
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

When you read a csv, each line represents variables separated by a special char, in your case, comas: ",".

You can get each variable separated by doing `line_variables = row.split(',')`

Just pass the first line, and for all the other, do something like:

```
result = {
   "claimsHeader":" {
    "claimId": line_variables[0],
    "subscriberId": line_variables[1],
    "claimType":{
        "code": line_variables[2]
    }
...
```

Finaly, just add the result to a list (created just before your for loop) with `your_list.append(result)`.